# Was the window.print support removed by Firefox Quantum?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, printing, firefox-quantum

I use in angular 1.6.6 in a controller the call

`$window.print();`

Its does work with ie, firefox and chrome but its does not work with firefox quantum at an lenovo tablet.

- Has firefox quantum removed the print function?
- Could firefox quantum only print via addons?
- Is the `$window.print()` no standard print function?
- Is there a setting of firefox quantum which i have to enable?

Thanks for answers.

**Update**:

- Does work means: print dialog popup.
- Does not work means: No dialog popup, no share to printer dialog opened - the print is not going on for the user.
- test with chrome and firefox quantum was at lenovo tablet with android
- test with ie and firefox was at window 7 desktop

Hint:
A print css via `@media print` is present.

Comment: Did you mean `window.print()` It is working for me on MacOS Sierra

Comment: Since Angular $window service is basically `window`, it's not AngularJS question and it should be same with raw JS. It's unclear what 'does not work' mean. Of course, it cannot be removed because it's basic functionality. Unless you see 'is not a function' error in console, there's no reason to assume that. It's unclear what platform this 'lenovo tablet' is and if 'ie, firefox and chrome' are used on the same device.

Comment: The question is misleading then because it jumps into conclusions. It's not evident that window.print worked on Android in earlier Firefox versions. It's unclear what Android version is affected. It's not evident that window.print doesn't work in Firefox Quantum on Windows. It would be much simpler to test that it works in Firefox Quantum on Windows (and I see no reasons why it shouldn't) and then narrow down the problem to Android.

Comment: @estus: Yes you are right. 
Sorry i dont have permissions to install firefox quantum in the intranet of company which works at win7 platform. At home i dont have window. But I will be look at home for more tests with linux. Maybe the behaivior is the same like the android tablet.
And i will be install a older firefox at android tablet to test it too. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Android had a history of printing issues, so that's most probable scenario. I can't think of other reasons. I'd suggest to use portable browsers if you have permissions for that https://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable

Comment: OK, there are related questions which point too in direction of mobile device browsers print problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21566052/feature-detection-solution-for-window-print-javascript?rq=1

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268840/determine-whether-browser-supports-printing

Comment: I have tested at my android tablet with firefox versions 57 and 58.02b and in both versions no printing is available. Next test is planned for linux with latest firefox version.