# window.print() dialog not showing in Chrome wher it works fine in IE , Firefox and Safari

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing

Print dialog is not showing in Chrome

```
 var newWin = window.open("","",'width=0,height=0');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            url: '/BarcodePrintTest/PrintBarcodeLabel1',
            data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data != "") {
                    newWin.document.write('</head><body >');
                    newWin.document.write(JSON.stringify(data.replace(/\r\n/g, "<br/>")));
                    newWin.document.write('</body></html>');
                    newWin.document.close();
                    newWin.resizeTo(0, 0);
                    newWin.moveTo(0, window.screen.availHeight + 10);
                    newWin.focus();
                    newWin.print();
                   // setTimeout(function () { newWin.close(); }, 1);
                    newWin.close();
                    return false;
                   // window.location = '@Url.Action("Create", "BarcodePrintTest")';
                }
                newWin.close();
                return false;
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Error in print');
            }
```

This is my code ...
It is prompting print dialoge in Firefox,IE and Safari perfectly but didn't promt the dialog in chrome browser.
Have gone through many threds but unable to produce solution.

Comment: most common question in `SO`, not working in this `browser` ;)

Comment: yup..do we have any solution for this

Comment: Also, See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24947993/window-print-method-is-not-working)

Comment: @NavinRauniyar may be my answer will be helpful to ur post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it works for me in chrome.

Here is my code

```
 var newWin = window.open("","",'width=0,height=0');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            url: '/BarcodePrintTest/PrintBarcodeLabel1',
            data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data != "") {
                    debugger
                    if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1) {   // Chrome Browser Detected?
                        newWin.PPClose = false;                                     // Clear Close Flag
                        newWin.onbeforeunload = function () {                         // Before Window Close Event
                            if (newWin.PPClose === false) {                           // Close not OK?
                                return 'Leaving this page will block the parent window!\nPlease select "Stay on this Page option" and use the\nCancel button instead to close the Print Preview Window.\n';
                            }
                        }
                        newWin.document.write('</head><body >');
                        newWin.document.write(JSON.stringify(data.replace(/\r\n/g, "<br/>")));
                        newWin.document.write('</body></html>');
                        newWin.document.close();
                       // newWin.resizeTo(0, 0);
                        //newWin.moveTo(0, window.screen.availHeight + 10);
                       // newWin.focus();
                        newWin.print();                                             // Print preview
                        newWin.close();
                        newWin.PPClose = true;                                      // Set Close Flag to OK.
                    }
```