# ionic 4 how to get a page in normal size when printing

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, printing, progressive-web-apps

When i open safari in app browser and try to print a page hosted on firebase with ionic 4 pwa, i get a pdf with the content page but for somehow it is really small (like device screen size) and other pages like google etc. i get the page normal size on pdf, does any one know how can i print the page on normal size? if you need some code of the pwa or the application please let me know.

the pwa page is https://pwannova.firebaseapp.com/home
and i use the following command to print on the button "link":
'''window.print()'''
if i access this site from a computer works fine:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hr9dJ.png) but in mobile device don't, if you see the black line will understand what I mean: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpp4H.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [window print method is not working in ipad chrome browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24947993/window-print-method-is-not-working-in-ipad-chrome-browser)

Comment: Hi unfortunately don't. But thank you. The window.print() works on mobile but its not in a proportional size (normal size pdf) like with other sites. I will post some print later